What do you call it when someone's really pushing it?
In Iraqi Arabic, when someone is bothering you or hassling you continuously and you reach that level where you can't handle it (like when they begin insulting you), you literally say to them (in Arabic) "dude you're really darkening it". The word darkening in Arabic also means they've pushed the limits of the situation and you're about to lose your temper. Example scenario:

You scratched my car, you're not just gonna pay for that, I'll give you a beating too!
*Man, you're really [insert word] it now. Enough!"

Maybe "pushing it" is the right way to describe this expression. But I'm looking for a single word (if it exists). I was also thinking of "milking it", but this involves swindling and money (in addition to it being two words). Idioms are welcome too.
Addendum: Some nice suggestions. Might I add that the expression does NOT have to involve two people having a go at each other. The expression can also be used to signify your reaction towards something you see on TV (i.e. the news), some altercation you witness, violent protests, etc...
For instance, say an extreme bill is passed in congress (after a moderate one), and you passionately disagree with it because it's so over the top, you would exclaim, "My God, these people are really now [insert word] it".

Cruising for a bruising?

Darkening it and pushing it are the same number of words.

Not a word, but phrases 'taking it too far'  and 'crossing the line' are most commonly used in my experience.

Another idiom is 'playing with fire'.

Don't you think the question itself presumes that every language must have a corresponding special word for this kind of situation?  One of the wonderful things about language is surely that there is not always a 'mot juste' for everything.  The English translation of 'mot juste' ('right word') just doesn't quite do it.  There must be expressions in Arabic like that.  What is the the word/expression?

A single word is too restrictive a goal; I can't think of a suitsable word. I would use "You're pushing your luck".

@Lambie I'd suggest you put this in the "answers" section and include the dictionary entry. It's a decent suggestion, although not exactly what I'm looking for (as it involves two words).

@DJohnson Another good suggestion, albeit more on the violent side (which wasn't what I was looking for specifically). I'd recommend that you put it in the "answers" section. I will count it as an official answer for now.

To further Tuffy's answer, English commonly uses phrasal verbs where other languages use a single word (or in German, maybe a separable verb). You might find some rare single word, but if you want something commonly used, then a phrasal verb is best. It sounds like you're looking for something colloquial and commonly used from your examples, but say if you do want something literary and obscure.


Man, you're really asking for trouble now. Enough!


Asking for trouble/it (idiom)
Behaving in a way that is likely to cause problems for you
Cambridge


Ask for it (informal)
To behave in a way that invites punishment or
retribution
Ask for trouble (informal)
To behave in a way that is likely to
result in trouble
M-W


Many possibilities here. One that you could try is overstep the mark.

To go further or do more than one should or is permitted.

I really feel like you overstepped the mark when you started criticizing John's ability as a parent.
overstep the mark

I do like this one. Excellent suggestion.

On thin ice is an idiom describing a scenario where someone is pushing boundaries to their breaking point. It is usually spoken as a warning by the aggrieved party, informing the line-stepper that they will soon suffer the consequences of their actions if they continue.

Cruising for a bruising.
From the Wiktionary: Following a course of action likely to result in injury or other trouble for oneself.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6vzsXJ0D2bM

Phrases include
Sir, you go too far.
You are pushing my buttons
(Merriam-Webster)
You are pressing your luck
(Merriam-Webster)

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

According to the SOED, the verb "to overreact" would be adequate, as the implication "you are going beyond the limit" is clear. With this verb "it" is not needed.

(SOED) overreact   Respond more forcibly than is justified, react too strongly.


Man, you're really overreacting now. Enough!


This doesn't fit. There is no requirement that a person pushing boundaries is reacting to anything at all; something that isn't even a reaction in the first place certainly can't be an overreaction. Someone goading you into a response isn't overreacting.

@NuclearHoagie "Pushing boundaries" is a very general term: you can push the boundaries of anything, genre, fantasy, technological innovation, cruelty, etc. However, here it is clear that the boundaries being "pushed" are those of a reaction, the reaction to someone having damaged one's property. The normal reaction is to ask for compensation, but to envisage to beat the person responsible for the damage is clearly an overreaction, from all points of view, in particular from the legal point of view.

Yes, violence is certainly an overreaction in this case. But the OP isn't looking for a word to describe the aggrieved person and what they do in response, they're looking for a word to describe the one who pushes someone else to a response. If someone scratches your car, they are pushing boundaries, and you may overreact by beating them. They are not overreacting (or reacting at all).

@NuclearHoagie That is not so: who is saying [insert word] is the person that scratched the car; the person whose car has been scratched is the one pushing their behaviour beyond normal limits. Anyway, if someone scratches your car, even on purpose, you are not going to say that they are pushing the limits.; either it is an accident, and there is really no reason for saying that, or they did it out of meanness  and then they are simply considered to have acted criminally.
